# CMake dependencies - How to build root before building subdirectories

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies

In ROOT folder, I have a CMakeFiles.txt that contains: add_subdirectory(gtest). Problem is, ROOT builds a file called API which is required for gtest to build correctly.

API has dependencies on files generated by ROOT. How can I get it so that API waits until ROOT is completely finished building before executing API's CMakeList? Is there some sort of delay I can add?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your files it's hard to give details, but you just have to tell CMake that gtest depends on API. With that information, CMake will generate things in the appropriate order.

Comment: What would be the command? I have Project(root) and Project(gtest), do I just add add_dependencies(gtest root) into the CMake of gtest?

Comment: I basically want everything to be done building in ROOT before starting to build gtest...how can I do this? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: That's the wrong way to think about it. CMake doesn't understand "do this then do this then do this". Instead, you tell it what depends on what, and it figures out a sequence for building things that ensures that all the pieces that are needed are in place before starting to build another piece. If gtest depends on everything in root, fine, set up the dependency and you'll get what you want. If there are pieces of root that gtest doesn't depend on, don't try to force CMake to build everything in root; it will ensure that everything is built in time to be used.